# Get used/unused database capacity in SQL Azure Federation

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

How could I retrieve the size (in MB or GB) of all federated databases in SQL Azure Federation? What's the TSQL for getting the used space and unused space across all members?

Answer (score 0):

you can do a fan-out query to each federation member. for a sample of doing fan-out queries, have a look at http://federationsutility-seasia.cloudapp.net/

for example, you can fire this query on the utility to get db size for each member:

SELECT SUM(reserved_page_count) * 8192 FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats